# Can WCF inactivity timeout be changed during runtime?

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout

I have a WCF service and client using reliable session. 
Inactivity timeout is set to 1 minute during creation of the service but I need to change this timeout dynamically during runtime to, say, 10 minutes for some time and then set back to 1 minute.

I have tried changing timeout interval before creating of service. 
This works of course, although I am not able to change it during runtime.
I also tried to increase another timeouts like Send, Receive and Operation at the same time but it didn't help.

So the question is - is it even possible to change inactivity timeout during runtime or not? If so, should I change any other timeout to make it work?

I changed the timeout in one of my contract implementation methods like this.
Although the timeout is correctly set to 10 minutes, it still behaves like it did with the default timeout.

```cs
var binding = OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Endpoints.First().Binding as CustomBinding;
binding.Elements.Find<ReliableSessionBindingElement>().InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Endpoints.ToList().First().Binding = binding;
```

Comment: When a servicehost is opened, it can no longer be configured, unfortunately. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.open?view=netframework-4.8) (check the remarks on the Open() overload). It does seem to be [possible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2010/01/21/how-to-change-net-configuration-files-at-runtime-including-for-wcf/) through the config file though.